# Widget showing adsense code, not the ad

Tags: wordpress, adsense

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVDbc.jpg)

I have added the adsense code in the widget area. And it's not showing any ad in the front-end. It's showing full code

[screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxp3g.jpg)

Comment: share your admin area screenshot

Comment: it is text widget?

Comment: @dev see the screenshot-2 please

Answer (score 0):

It happened because you need to use Custom HTML widget instead of Text widget.

Comment: I added custom html now. But it is showing now just a yellow box now

Answer (score 0):

Change the editor mode from 'Visual' to 'Text' then paste your advertisement code. 
[image: check this screenshot]